# Use minted for color syntax highlighting of listings and pyluatex for execute python code

Tags: tcolorbox, minted, pyluatex

I'm using `minted` to color and display snippets of python code, which are embedded in a tcolorbox with the definition `\newtcblisting` (`codepy` environment below).

I would like to create an other environment called `codepyexec` that would do the same as `codepy`, but additionally run the python code (environment `python`) with the recently released `pyluatex` package on CTAN. How to do this ?

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{manni}
%
\usepackage[verbose]{pyluatex}
%
\RequirePackage[skins,breakable,xparse,many,minted]{tcolorbox}
\tcbsetforeverylayer{%
    enhanced,
    coltitle            = black   ,
    colbacktitle        = white   ,
    boxrule             = 0.5pt   ,
    colback             = white   ,
    breakable                     ,
    arc                 = 2mm     ,
    size                = title   ,
    toprule at break    = 0mm     ,
    bottomrule at break = 0mm     ,
    lower separated     = false   ,
    boxed title style ={size=small, boxrule=0pt, colframe=white,} ,
    fonttitle           = \bfseries\sffamily ,
    varwidth boxed title ,
    before app          = \parfillskip0pt
}
%
\newtcblisting{mintedpython}[1][]{
    listing engine=minted,
    minted language=python,
    minted options={autogobble,breaklines,breakanywhere}    ,
    listing only,
    skin=enhancedmiddle jigsaw, % Rule D/G uniquement
    enlarge top initially by = 2.5mm,
    rightrule=0mm,
    leftrule=2mm,
    arc=0mm,
    outer arc=0mm,
    left=3.4mm,
    titlerule=0mm,
    detach title,
    attach title to upper={\ \quad \ },
    IfValueTF={#1}{title={#1}}{},
    }
%
\newenvironment{codepy}{\VerbatimEnvironment\begin{mintedpython}%
    }{
    \end{mintedpython}
    }
%
%\newenvironment{codepyexec}{\VerbatimEnvironment...
%   }{
%   ...
%   }
    
%   
\begin{document}

\begin{codepy}
x = 1
print(x)

def f(x):
    return x**2
\end{codepy}

%codepyexec should do this : 
%\begin{codepy}
%x = 1
%print(x)
%
%def f(x):
%   return x**2
%\end{codepy}
%AND
%\begin{python}
%x = 1
%print(x)
%
%def f(x):
%   return x**2
%\end{python}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Using external files makes it easy to obtain the feature you want. Do you need to type the code in your LaTeX file?

Comment: External `py` files ? This would involve creating too many files and would be complicated to manage.

Comment: I am currently a `pythontex` user (where you can do this easily) but I prefer pyluatex which only requires one compilation.

Comment: Today I have looked at the documentation of `pyluatex` and the solution of your problem is in the example on page 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For information, here is a way to have the same functionalities with the package `piton` instead of `minted`. The Python codes are executed with `pyluatex` (which requires the use of LuaLaTeX) but the syntactical coloring is done by the package `piton` (that package does not require external tools, unlike `minted` which uses the external program Pygments).

```
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage[verbose]{pyluatex}

\usepackage{piton}

\RequirePackage[skins,breakable,xparse,many]{tcolorbox}
\tcbsetforeverylayer{
    enhanced,
    coltitle=black,
    colbacktitle=white,
    boxrule=0.5pt,
    colback=white,
    breakable,
    arc=2mm,
    size=title,
    toprule at break=0mm,
    bottomrule at break=0mm,
    lower separated=false,
    boxed title style={size=small,boxrule=0pt,colframe=white},
    fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily,
    varwidth boxed title,
    before app=\parfillskip0pt,
}

\newtcolorbox{tcbpitonpython}[1][]{
    skin=enhancedmiddle jigsaw,
    enlarge top initially by=2.5mm,
    rightrule=0mm,
    leftrule=2mm,
    arc=0mm,
    outer arc=0mm,
    left=3.4mm,
    titlerule=0mm,
    detach title,
    attach title to upper={\ \quad \ },
    IfValueTF={#1}{title={#1}}{},
}


\NewPitonEnvironment{pitonpython}{}
  { \begin{tcbpitonpython} }
  { \end{tcbpitonpython} }



\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function pytypeset()
    tex.print("\\begin{pitonpython}")
    tex.print(pyluatex.get_last_code())
    tex.print("\\end{pitonpython}")
    tex.print("") -- ensure newline
end
\end{luacode}

\newenvironment{codepyexec}
{\PyLTVerbatimEnv\begin{pythonq}}
{\end{pythonq}
\directlua{pytypeset()}
% Optional: print Python output (enable next line)
% Output: \directlua{tex.print(pyluatex.get_last_output())}
}

\begin{document}


\begin{codepyexec}
x = 1
print(x)

def f(x):
  return x**2
\end{codepyexec}

% Check whether code was not only typeset but also executed:
\py{f(3)}

\end{document}
```

[image: Output of the above code]

Answer (score 1):

The desired functionality is available since v0.3.0 with the `\PyLTVerbatimEnv` macro.

For example:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{manni}
\usepackage[verbose]{pyluatex}

\RequirePackage[skins,breakable,xparse,many,minted]{tcolorbox}
\tcbsetforeverylayer{
    enhanced,
    coltitle=black,
    colbacktitle=white,
    boxrule=0.5pt,
    colback=white,
    breakable,
    arc=2mm,
    size=title,
    toprule at break=0mm,
    bottomrule at break=0mm,
    lower separated=false,
    boxed title style={size=small,boxrule=0pt,colframe=white},
    fonttitle=\bfseries\sffamily,
    varwidth boxed title,
    before app=\parfillskip0pt,
}

\newtcblisting{mintedpython}[1][]{
    listing engine=minted,
    minted language=python,
    minted options={autogobble,breaklines,breakanywhere},
    listing only,
    skin=enhancedmiddle jigsaw,
    enlarge top initially by=2.5mm,
    rightrule=0mm,
    leftrule=2mm,
    arc=0mm,
    outer arc=0mm,
    left=3.4mm,
    titlerule=0mm,
    detach title,
    attach title to upper={\ \quad \ },
    IfValueTF={#1}{title={#1}}{},
}

\usepackage{luacode}
\begin{luacode}
function pytypeset()
    tex.print("\\begin{mintedpython}")
    tex.print(pyluatex.get_last_code())
    tex.print("\\end{mintedpython}")
    tex.print("") -- ensure newline
end
\end{luacode}

\newenvironment{codepyexec}
{\PyLTVerbatimEnv\begin{pythonq}}
{\end{pythonq}
\directlua{pytypeset()}
% Optional: print Python output (enable next line)
% Output: \directlua{tex.print(pyluatex.get_last_output())}
}

\begin{document}

\begin{codepyexec}
x = 1
print(x)

def f(x):
  return x**2
\end{codepyexec}

% Check whether code was not only typeset but also executed:
\py{f(3)}

\end{document}
```